# Как сделать, чтобы на полном разрешении браузера входила вся картинка на экран?

Tags: css3

Добрый день, дамы и господа. Сложился следующий вопрос:

1. Есть картинка размером `1024х657`
2. Картинка должна вставать фоном на сайт и масштабироваться под размер браузера. Нашел один из выходов из данной ситуации, только немного не доработанный. Помогите довести его до ума.

Пишу следующий CSS код

```
body {
       background: url(nature.jpg) center center fixed no-repeat;
       -moz-background-size: cover; /* Firefox до 4.0 */
       -webkit-background-size: cover; /* Safari и Chrome */
       -o-background-size: cover; /* Opera до версии 10.53 */
      background-size: cover; /* CSS3 */
    }

    @media only all and (max-width: 1023px) and (max-height: 657px) {
      body {
        -webkit-background-size: 1023px 657px;/* Safari и Chrome */
          -o-background-size: 1023px 657px;/* Opera до версии 10.53 */
        -moz-background-size: 1023px 657px; /* Firefox до 4.0 */
        background-size: 1023px 657px; /* CSS3 */
      }
    }
```

Ситуация следующая: часть картинки в экран на полном разрешении браузера не входит. Как сделать, чтобы входила вся картинка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Cover** и **contain** масштабируют фоновое изображение с сохранением пропорций. При этом **contain** вписывает изображение целиком (если пропорции картинки и экрана не совпадают, появляется пустое место), **cover** жертвует частью картинки, чтобы фон был целиком закрыт.

```
body {
  background: url(nature.jpg) center center fixed no-repeat;
  -moz-background-size: contain; /* Firefox до 4.0 */
  -webkit-background-size: contain; /* Safari и Chrome */
  -o-background-size: contain; /* Opera до версии 10.53 */
  background-size: contain; /* CSS3 */
}
```

В обоих случаях указывать точные размеры не нужно, поэтому вторую часть вашего кода можно опустить.

Comment: Но при таком своийстве остается белый край справа или слева или при другом разрешении сверху или снизу

Comment: Мой косяк. Поспешил и перепутал поведение свойств. Исправил свой ответ.

Answer (score 1):

А если html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }, img { width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 0; } попробовать? При любых разрешениях всегда будет на весь экран.

Comment: вроде еще img{position:absolute .z-index=-1}?

Comment: лучше fixed :)

Comment: наверно да.Спс